# Adding html table to javascript using document.write

Tags: javascript, html

Looking for some help here.  Our class instructor is asking us to add a table into javascript using the document.write, I know this is not the recommended way to do this, but this is what our instructor is looking for:
Add code to the writeIt function that writes the opening table tag before iterating thru the heros and villians and then the closing table tag.  Then modify the makeListItem to return a string in the form of tr td Hero td td Villan /td /tr.

I tried this but am getting a blank html page when try to view.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript Functions</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
      var superData = {"Super Man":["Lex Luther"],
                       "Bat Man":["Joker", "Riddler",],
                       "Spider Man":["Green Goblin", 
                                     "Vulture", "Carnage"],
                       "Thor":["Loki", "Frost Giants"]};
      function writeIt('<table>'){
        for (hero in superData){
          var villains = superData[hero];
          for (villainIdx in villains){
            var villain = villains[villainIdx];
            var listItem = makeListItem(<tr><td>Hero</td><td>Villan</td></tr>);
            document.write(listItem);
          }
        }
      }
      function makeListItem(name, value){
        var itemStr = "<li>" + name + ":&nbsp;" + value + "</li>";
        return itemStr;
      }
        document.write('</table>');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="writeIt()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're wanting to add DOM elements to the HTML **from** JavaScript, not **to** JavaScript. In that case, a simple search on "How to add dom elements from javascript" will yield you every kind of result you need.

Comment: Remove `'<table>'` from your `writeIt` function declaration. It's not doing anything. You also need to actually write your table element to the document, in the same way that you write your closing tag.

Comment: There are, however, more underlying issues with your code. For example, you are never writing a starting `<table>` tag, you are using a string as a parameter in your `writeIt` function definition (which is not valid), you are passing only 1 argument to the `makeListItem` function, and it's not valid, syntactically. At minimum, it would need to be wrapped in quotes (to make it a string). Sounds like you may need to spend some more time reading up on basic JavaScript, or speak with your professor during office hours.

Comment: Don't use `document.write()`. It's ancient and has almost no practical usage on today's web. Learn about **DOM scripting** instead.

Comment: It looks like you really need to brush up on how Javascript works. As it stands, your code is invalid and needs a fundamental overhaul. Test your code as you write it instead of writing the whole thing out and hoping it works. You would have caught these issues sooner if you took your time.

Comment: Voting to close as I believe the answer to this question is much more broad than would fit within the question guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JavaScript Functions</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script>
    var superData = {
      "Super Man": ["Lex Luther"],
      "Bat Man": ["Joker", "Riddler", ],
      "Spider Man": ["Green Goblin",
        "Vulture", "Carnage"
      ],
      "Thor": ["Loki", "Frost Giants"]
    };

    function writeIt() {
      document.write('<table>');
      for (hero in superData) {
        document.write("<tr><td>" + hero + ": <ul>");
        var villains = superData[hero];
        for (villainIdx in villains) {
          var villain = villains[villainIdx];
          var listItem = makeListItem(villain);
          document.write(listItem);
        }
        document.write("</ul></td></tr>");
      }
    }

    function makeListItem(value) {
      var itemStr = "<li>" + value + "</li>";
      return itemStr;
    }
    document.write('</table>');
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="writeIt()">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should add an explanation of what you changed and why. Just posting code is not helpful for learning. Since SO is not a code-writing service, our goal is to help the OP (and future visitors) learn and understand better.

Comment: I agree. I should have but didn't have the time to. There was SO MUCH wrong in this javascript. Just down vote this answer and we will all feel better.

Comment: I won't downvote, but I won't upvote until the answer is useful

Comment: The javascript was copied from our assignment file in sams teach  yourself angularjs, javascript and jquery, I didn't write it.

Comment: If this was truly copy and pasted, blindly fixing it for the OP can be problematic.  If the purpose is to learn, we shouldn't be doing the entire assignment for the OP, but rather helping the OP understand the complexities of it and what's needed to fix it themself.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried this but am getting a blank html page when try to view.

Because you have syntax problems.  Use F12 or the Inspector/Developer mode to find out why.

> Our class instructor is asking us to add a table into javascript using the document.write, I know this is not the recommended way to do this, but this is what our instructor is looking for

True, it's often frowned upon, but JavaScript makes it available for a reason, so let's use it.

The first problem is that you seem to have transposed some code...

For example, you have `function writeIt('<table>')`.  I think you meant `document.write('<table>');`.

```
function writeIt(){
   document.write('<table>');
```

Next, you have your final `document.write` outside of your function call.

```
    document.write('</table>');
```

This should be inside `writeIt()`, just after your for loop.

Finally, you have some unquoted stuff in your loop...

```
makeListItem(<tr><td>Hero</td><td>Villan</td></tr>);
```

Should be (single or double quotes):

```
makeListItem('<tr><td>Hero</td><td>Villan</td></tr>');
```

But that's still a bit off for a table.  For example, Superman has a 1:1 ratio with his villains and Batman has a 1:2 ratio.  You should be adding your rows and tables in a more predictable manner, but the above will at least start to give you output to work from.

Finally, an observation is that your `makeListItem` needs to use `<ul>` before it uses `<li>` so those problems need to be resolved.  For now, I recommend you just spit the data out and format it later.